# Get selected value of dynamic controls Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I need to get the selected value of the dropdown and upload file details on submit button click in a angular application.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div *ngFor="let item of controls; let pointIndex=index" [formGroupName]="pointIndex">
      <label>
        Selling Point: <select>
          <option *ngFor="res of objArrValues" [value]="res.value">{{res.name}}</option>
        </select>
      </label>

      <label for="file">Choose File</label>
      <input type="file"
             id="file"
             (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files, pointIndex)">
             <button type="button" (click)="deleteSellingPoint(pointIndex)">Delete</button>
    </div>
    <button type="button" (click)="getDetails()">Add</button>
  </div>
```

Typescript (Something like this):

```
getDetails()
{
     //something like a array of controls to iterate and get the values

     for(let i=0; i< controls.length; i++)
       {
          obj.id = arr[i].dropdownValue;
          obj.file = arr[i].selectedFile;
       }
}
```

i tried to do it in the change event of both the controls which didn't work. Is there anyway to iterate over the controls on submit and get the values?

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to do that to get the select value just use ngModel:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectValue">
          <option *ngFor="res of objArrValues" [value]="res.value">{{res.name}}</option>
        </select>
```

and declare a variable in you're ts file named selectValue,You can do this also for your input.

Comment: What will i get for multiple controls??

Comment: For each control you define an specific variable and that variable reflects the current value of that control, select shows the selected option value and input shows the input string

Answer (score 1):

You can also use (change) event in select statement like below,

```
<select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
  <option *ngFor="let res of objArrValues" [value]="res.value">
     {{res.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

In your .ts file you can get the selected value using onChange func like,

```
onChange(selectedValue)
{
   //you will get the selected value here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the usage of formArray. Look here on how to use that https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/

In your case it would look roughly like this:

TS:

```
@Component(...)
class MyComp {
   public form:FormGroup = this.fb.group({
      someKey: this.fb.array([      // This is the array of controls we iterate over
         this.fb.group({/*...*/}), // Each entry in your array
         this.fb.group({/*...*/})  // And another entry in your array
      ])
   });

   constructor(private fb:FormBuilder) {}

   public getDetails() {
      const formValueAsArray = this.form.get('someKey').value; // Just get the value as a normal array
      // now do what you want with the array
   }

}
```

Template:

```
<div>
   <!-- Only changed the following line -->
   <div *ngFor="let item of form.get('someKey').controls; let pointIndex=index" formArrayName="someKey">
   <label>
   Selling Point: <select>
      <option *ngFor="res of objArrValues" [value]="res.value">{{res.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </label>

  <label for="file">Choose File</label>
  <input type="file"
         id="file"
         (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files, pointIndex)">
         <button type="button" (click)="deleteSellingPoint(pointIndex)">Delete</button>
</div>
<button type="button" (click)="getDetails()">Add</button>
```